# Exception While Creating ErpConfigContext

Tags: s4sdk

I'm getting this error while I'm trying to create `ErpConfigContext`.
Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Code snippet:

```
 @Bean
public ErpConfigContext erpConfigContext() {
    return new ErpConfigContext("S4HANA_CLOUD");
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
  *Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.connectivity.ErpConfigContext]: Factory method 'erpConfigContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast class com.sap.core.connectivity.apiext.cloud.configuration.CloudConnectivityConfiguration to interface com.sap.core.connectivity.api.configuration.ConnectivityConfiguration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 59 common frames omitted*


*Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: **Cannot cast class com.sap.core.connectivity.apiext.cloud.configuration.CloudConnectivityConfiguration to interface com.sap.core.connectivity.api.configuration.ConnectivityConfiguration**
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpNeoDestinationFacade.lookupConnectivityConfiguration(ScpNeoDestinationFacade.java:40)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpNeoDestinationFacade.getConnectivityConfiguration(ScpNeoDestinationFacade.java:59)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpNeoDestinationFacade.getDestinationConfiguration(ScpNeoDestinationFacade.java:69)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpNeoDestinationFacade.getGenericDestination(ScpNeoDestinationFacade.java:105)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationAccessor.getGenericDestination(DestinationAccessor.java:146)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.connectivity.ErpConfigContext.<init>(ErpConfigContext.java:209)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.connectivity.ErpConfigContext.<init>(ErpConfigContext.java:355)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.connectivity.ErpConfigContext.<init>(ErpConfigContext.java:429)
    at com.sap.csc.timebackend.config.S4Beans.erpConfigContext(S4Beans.java:20)
    at com.sap.csc.timebackend.config.S4Beans$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5076fc70.CGLIB$erpConfigContext$1(<generated>)
    at com.sap.csc.timebackend.config.S4Beans$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5076fc70$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bc447478.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at com.sap.csc.timebackend.config.S4Beans$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5076fc70.erpConfigContext(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 60 common frames omitted*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the scope of this dependency to test because I use it only with this purpose:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sap.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo-java-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a classloader issue, because `CloudConnectivityConfiguration` is definitely implementing `ConnectivityConfiguration`, see the class diagram below. Most likely the class and interface have been loaded by different class loaders.

Are you using Spring devtools? This can be a source for such isses, see [the reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools-customizing-classload) for an explanation and potential fix.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this hint. It helped me a lot while I was debugging. The problem was that I added the neo-java-web-api artifact from com.sap.cloud group. I use this for testing purpose and this caused the conflict. Changing the scope for test fixed the issue.